# Local Interface to an external SOAP web service (C#)

Tags: c#, web-services, oop, design-patterns, interface

I want to access methods of an external class (web service) in the parent method (the web service is instantiated in the child class)

The scenario is such :
I have a mother class called ConvertCurrency which takes in dollars and gives Rupees. 
Eg. int ConvertCurrency(int dollars);

Now there is a standard vendor out there in the market which provides a software that anybody can host on his server and create a webservice. So, lets say it is hosted at two places : www.link-A.com/service.asmx and www.link-B.com/service.asmx.

I have a parent class : CurrencyConvertor, and it has two subclasses : Convertor-A and Convertor-B.

```
Class CurrencyConvertor
{
    protected Object Service;

    public Convert(int dollars)
    {
        Service.ConvertCurrency(dollars);
    }
}

Class Convertor-A : CurrencyConvertor
{
    public Convertor-A()
    {
        Service = link-A.service;
    }
}

Class Convertor-B : CurrencyConvertor
{
    public Convertor-B()
    {
        Service = link-B.service;
    }
}


// based on current response-time of the two servers, we decide 
// that B is faster and hence we make the decision at run-time that we should use 
// B's service

CurrencyConvertor cc = new Convertor-B();
cc.Convert(5);
```

But this won't compile because the parent class doesn't know what all methods Service has and it gives the following error :

'object' does not contain a definition for 'GetSources' and no extension method 'GetSources' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I'm wondering as to what can be a possible solution for this problem. Of course, without having to resort to creating a separate Convert function for each of the two providers.

If I can somehow make "service" Object aware of its interface (i.e. function signatures), it will work just fine.

Is there a way to get around this problem ?

Comment: do converter a and b inherit from CurrencyConverter?

Comment: Yes @Stephan. Thanks for pointing that out :) Have update the code to reflect the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got a solution to this problem using reflection (courtesy Manas Agarwal)

```
Class CurrencyConvertor cc;
cc = new Convertor-A();

BindingFlags flags = (BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly);
MethodInfo m = cc.type.GetMethod(MethodName, flags);
response = (string)m.Invoke(cc.Service, Parameters);
```

Answer (score 0):

Create an abstract method in CurrencyConvertor that is called GetService();
the deriving classes will have to implement this method in the way that they return the service ...

*in CurrencyConverter:*

```
 public abstract IMyNewServiceThingy GetService();
```

The base class can now use this class to get the service and call methods on it

*In every deriving class:*

```
public override IMyNewServiceThingy GetService()
{
   return Service;
}
```

Setting the Service variable on class - levlel is a bad decision, even worse, when you reset it when creating a derived class (in the constructors) - you can never know which Service is currently set.. (esp. when using IOC or asynchronous calls)

Comment: The problem I'm running into here is that the type of the two services are different. The one for A is link-A.service and for B is link-B.service (link-A and link-B refer to the two namespaces that we get on adding the two web references). Now, in the base class, I have to set this as :

public abstract Object GetServices();

And in my program, I do :

Object service = cc.GetService();

Now, when I call any of the method service, I'll get the same error - 'object' does not contain a definition for 'GetSources' 

I'm new to OOP, so please let me know If I have misinterpreted your soln.

Comment: when the method called on the service has the same signature for both services (both types) then create a common interface for both methods and return that.. hmm you might have some issues here with auto-generated code.. - dont know

Comment: sorry.. i forgot the return types.. object doesnt get you very far (unless you want to cast the object in the base-class or use reflection to invoke the method - but this is not necessary I think)

Comment: Thanks Stephan. I created the interface and added one method of the web service. In the child class, when I try to return the service by casting it to the interface, its failing.

public override IWebService GetService()
{
    return (IWebService)link-A.service;
}

interface IWebService
{
    int ConvertCurrency(int dollars);
    // need to add rest of the methods of the web service
}

Here the explicit casting fails. I guess I'll complete the interface by adding all the methods that exist in the web service and see if the casting goes through.

Comment: "try to return the service by casting it to the interface" there would be no cast necessary.. when your class (the service-client-class) implements the interface you can just return the object as-is (you return an IMyNewServiceThingy - did you forget to add the interface to the client class?)

Comment: Sorry, didn't get you. In all the derived classes, I need to return the unique service in the GetService() function (corresponding to that particular class). Since these services are of different *types*, I'll need to cast them. Here is some sample code to explain the scenario - http://pastebin.com/vtNNiU5x . Please let me know if I'm going wrong somewhere.